# identifiing the simultaneous tasks in a TPL dataflow

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have 1000 elements in a TPL dataflow block,
each element will call external webservices.

the web service supports a maximum of 10 simultaneous calls, 
which is easily achieved using:

```
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
    ...
}
```

The web service requires each call to have a unique id passed which distinguises it from the other simultaneous calls. 
In theory this should be a guid, but in practise the 11th GUID will fail - because the throttling mechanism on the server is slow to recognise that the first call is finished.

The vendor suggests we recycle the guids, keeping 10 in active use.

I intend to have an array of GUIDS, each task will use (Interlocked.Increment(ref COUNTER) % 10 ) as the array index

*EDIT :
I just realised this won't work!
It assumes tasks will complete in order which they may not
I could implement this as a queue of IDs where each task borrows and returns one, but the question still stands, is there a an easier, pre bulit thread-safe way to do this?*

(there will never be enough calls for COUNTER to overflow)

But I've been surprised a number of times by C# (I'm new to .net) that I am implementing something that already exists.

Is there a better thread-safe way for each task to recycle from a pool of ids?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating resource pools is the exact situation `System.Collections.ConcurrentBag<T>` is useful for. Wrap it up in a `BlockingCollection<T>` to make the code easier.

```
class Example
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Guid> _guidPool;
    private readonly TransformBlock<Foo, Bar> _transform;     

    public Example(int concurrentLimit)
    {
        _guidPool = new BlockingCollection<Guid>(new ConcurrentBag<Guid>(), concurrentLimit)
        for(int i = 0: i < concurrentLimit; i++)
        {
            _guidPool.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
        }

        _transform = new TransformBlock<Foo, Bar>(() => SomeAction, 
                                                  new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                                                  {
                                                     MaxDegreeOfParallelism = concurrentLimit
                                                     //...
                                                  });
        //...
    }

    private async Task<Bar> SomeAction(Foo foo)
    {
        var id= _guidPool.Take();
        try
        {
             //...
        }
        finally
        {
            _guidPool.Add(id);
        }
    }
}
```